# C# share or modify variables between classes

Tags: c#, class, timer, scope

So I have 2 classes: Timers and KeyHook.

In the Timers class I have a public variable called lastInteraction of type DateTime.

The KeyHook class is responsible for listening to keyboard events. Currently it prints to the screen when a key is pressed.

**I want the KeyHook event to update the lastInteraction variable with the current DateTime, is that possible?** Even if I create the KeyHook instance within the timer class it doen't help.

How can I achieve such thing, I serached online but to the best of my knowledge a variable can't be shared across classes and passing the values around between classes won't work.

---

Some code snippets:

*Program.cs*

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BeatW.Timers timer = new BeatW.Timers();
    timer.startTimers();

    KeyHook kh = new KeyHook();

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

*KeyHook.cs*

```
public static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
        Console.WriteLine((Keys)vkCode);
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

*Timers.cs*

```
class Timers
{
    public DateTime lastInteraction;
    ...
}
```

Comment: You instantiate `KeyHook`, but the callback method is static. How is the instance connected to the static callback?

Comment: Rather do opposite, hook can update its `static` field/property, which you can read from instance methods.

Comment: Like others mention, I am also confused as to how your Keyhook and Timers classes are connected, but I would say that you probably want the Keyhook to fire an event and have the Timers class subscribe to it so that the lastInteraction value can be updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a static class it is possible to do what you want to.

```
public static class Timers
{
    public static DateTime lastInteraction { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And in the KeyHook class you can put values on it.

```
public static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
        >>>>>Timers.lastInteraction = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine((Keys)vkCode);
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

And you can access the value of `Timers.lastInteraction` on all namespace range at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Give `KeyHook` a delegate that updates `lastInteraction`:

```
class KeyHook {
    public static Action OnKey { get; set; }
    public static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) {
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN) {
            int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
            Console.WriteLine((Keys)vkCode);
            if (OnKey != null) {
                OnKey();
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
...
BeatW.Timers timer = new BeatW.Timers();
timer.startTimers();

KeyHook kh = new KeyHook();
KeyHook.OnKey = () => timer.lastInteraction = DateTime.Now;
```

**Note:** This is a quick-and-dirty way of achieving the functionality with little effort. Use [C# events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx) to build a more robust functionality, which lets you add, remove, and combine event handlers using C# facilities for handling events.

Comment: The code after the "...", is that supposed to be in the Timer class or the Program class?

Comment: It's from the `Main` of `Program`.