# Accessing variables across files

Tags: c#

I am new to programming and want to teach myself how to program C#. I've been going pretty smoothly and have been learning across from sites across the internet, but right now I've come across a little problem which I can't seem to find a solution to.

Im making a simple utility using Visual Studio and Blend and it consists of some custom user controls created via Blend.

One of these user controls is a toggle switch and to identify whether it is on or off, I created a boolean variable

```
private bool switchOn = false;
```

Essentially my goal is to update some text on the screen depending on the value of this Boolean.

The variable for the switch is stored on a file called - '*ToggleSwitch.xaml.cs*' **[FORM A]** and the text I want to update is stored on a file called '*MainWindow.xaml.cs*' **[FORM B]**.

How would I go about using the boolean variable from **[FORM A]** and implementing it into code used in **[FORM B]**.

I hope I have explained what I want to do clearly and would really appreciate it if anyone could help me with this.

Comment: The short answer is _likely_ to change `private bool switchOn = false;` to `public static bool switchOn = false;`

Comment: May be you need to use session to store user setting and read it on different pages. Session may not be ideal for large scale application, so you need to be more precise about your project architecture and type. Or else, if there is a database, store this value in database and access where you need.

Comment: Good job for trying to learn, and good job for asking questions! If the toggle is on the same page as the text you want to print, then you can probably access it by doing something like `if (mySwitch.switchOn) { // print }`. Here I assume that you have a variable called `mySwitch` that represents your switch. Also you would need to change the accessor of your variable (`private`) to `public`.

Comment: @mjwills Will doing this make the variable accessible from other files within the project or do i have to link the files somehow as well?

Comment: If it is in `Bob.xaml.cs` I suspect you will be able to access it using `Bob.switchOn` for example.

Comment: @Glubus wdym by 'on the same page'. The code for the switch and the code for the text are on 2 seperate files. I'm looking for a way to implement variables created in form 1 into form 2. Eg. if the switch turns off and `switchOn` is updated to be `false` on form 1, how would I go abouts grabbing the value of that variable and implementing it in form 2

Thanks again for your support!

Comment: @IsuruA When I say 'on the same page' I mean that I am there assuming that the switch is on the screen that also contains the text you want to output. If this is the case, then both the switch variable and the text variable should be accessible at the same time somewhere in your code. This means you need to find this point in your code, and use strategies like events to combine the two variables. If there is no way of accessing the variables because they are not rendered at the same time, it means you will have to communicate through a proxy, like a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two approaches:

1. Global variables (shared state). Simply make the variable *public static* in FormA. And then to access it use **FormA**.switchOn in **FormB**. Here is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45441063/c-sharp-share-or-modify-variables-between-classes) answered.
2. [Data Passing through events](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e3d1d8/data-passing-from-one-page-to-another-in-xaml/). This has a button-click event that reads in a value and then calls the other page (formA) using the URL (query string). That page (formB) then accesses the variable in question without it being globally accessible.

Heads up, generally (1) is a bad idea when going to production. Avoid shared state.